# Nodejs have an optional extra path in URL

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I'm developing part of a system where we have two applications sharing the same domain so nginx makes exampleurl.com go to one application and example.com/admin/* go to the second.

The /admin/* part is going to a NodeJs app using express.

Is there an elegant way of making sure that node can add in the /admin without having to do

```
app.get('/admin/endpoint', ...)
```

?

Comment: Read express docs. There is this case

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#router

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('One page in admin website');  
});

// router.get('/adminWebsite'); // idem for all routes(you always use this router)

app.use('/admin', router);
```

Answer (score 0):

you would would to use routers (preferably) but you can also create another express app. using different Apps allow you to have more global middlewear control whereas using different routes mean that they share the same express instance.

```js
var express = require('express');
var admin = express(); // <- this is now your admin application
var app = express(); // <- this is your main applicaiton regular users


//you will need to set up middlewear like body-parser and stuff for both of them now
//but it allows you to use different logging and authentication system or w.e you
//want

//once everything is done you can 'MOUNT' virtually the admin app to the regular app

app.use('/admin', admin); //<- this will nest apps together but allow the sub-app admin
//to be it's own instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

//app.js
`const admin = require('admin');` //you admin module (where you routes wiil be)

```
app.use('/admin', [functions... example authCheck], admin);
```

//index file of admin module

```
`var express     = require('express');
var router      = express.Router();

router.use(function authCheck(req, res, next) {
    //check if user is logged
});

router.get('/main', require('./main').get);

module.exports = router;`
```

//main.js

```
`exports.get = function(req, res, next){
        res.render('admin/admin', {
                title: "Main panel"
        });
};`
```

and now you can access site.com/admin/main